# Proving that $f(n) \geq n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

Here is the question in full:

Let $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be any function such that for $i \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(i) < f(i+1)$. Prove that $lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = L$, then $lim_{n \to \infty} x_{f(n)} = L$.

Note that my definition of $\mathbb{N}$ excludes $0$.

Here was my solution:

First we show that $f(n) \geq n$ for all $n \in N$ using induction.

Base case: $n = 1$, so we see $f(1) \geq 1$ because if not, then it would be a contradiction (we would get $f(1) = 0 \text{ or something negative} \notin \mathbb{N}$).

Inductive step: Suppose that $f(n) \geq n$. Prove that $f(n+1) \geq n$.

By assumption $f(n+1) > f(n)$ and by hypothesis $f(n) \geq n$ so this tells us that $f(n+1) \geq n$. Hence $f(n) \geq n$.

By definition of limit, we know there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|x_n - L| < \epsilon$ for $\epsilon > 0$.

Because $f(n) \geq n$, then $f(n) \geq n \geq N$ which implies, by definition, that $|x_{f(n)} - L| < \epsilon$, hence showing that $lim_{n \to \infty} x_{f(n)} = L$. QED

My question is: is this proof correct?

Comment: The "By assumption" line should be $f(n+1)>f(n)\ge n$ and since $f(n+1)$ is an integer then $f(n+1)>n\implies f(n+1)\ge n+1$.

Comment: $f(n+1) \geq n+1$

Answer (score 1):

$f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)<f(n+1)$ means that $f$ is strictly increasing in $\mathbb{N}$ that is $f(n)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

In other words the sequence $\{x_{f(n)}\}$ is a subsequence of a convergent sequence, therefore it converges.